# Merges columns outputs it as string

Tags: mysql

I am new to mySQL and got the exercise to implement a function which merges columns from one table and outputs it as a string, separated by CR (a CR after each record, i.e. separate the records by “\n”).

I have tried it already, but there appears an error which say: "SELECT MergeTablesAndOutputString(1) LIMIT 0, 1000.

What do I have to do differently that it works?

```html
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION  MergeTablesAndOutputString
(owner_id int) 
RETURNS varchar(50) 
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
DECLARE bname varchar(30);
DECLARE apno int(30);
DECLARE gno int(30);

set bname = Building.buildingName;
set apno = Building.apartmentno;
set gno = Building.garageno;

RETURN CONCAT(bname, '\n' + apno, ' \n', gno);
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The function know nothing about the building table - you need to pass columns to be concatenated as parameters and your select doesn't have a from..

Comment: *implement a function which merges columns from one table and outputs it as a string* What is the function argument - column names or their values for a record?

Comment: I have now revised it, is this the right approach?                                                                CREATE FUNCTION MergeTablesAndOutputString (owner_id int, buildingName varchar(50))
RETURNS varchar(50) DETERMINISTIC
RETURN CONCAT(owner_id, '\n', buildingName, '\n');